# Is it possible to trigger and then extend an event to another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have a poorly structured drop-down menu, something akin to:

```
<div class="regular"><a href="#">title</a></div>
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#">title</a>
    <div class="menu_wrapper">
        <a href="#">sub title</a>
        <a href="#">sub title</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this scenario, it's been built with `.menu_wrapper` having the property of `position:absolute;` resulting in a scenario where when the top level `.menu` is hovered over, `.menu_wrapper` isn't considered part of the same element therefore when attempting to hover over it a break is caused because it's no longer part of the same hover event.

I'm wondering if it's possible to have an event binder on `.menu` but then once the event is trigged, extend the binder to `.menu_wrapper` explicitly so that the "hover effect" is stable and working.

It seems like an easier solution than trying to re-arrange the bulk of poorly structured CSS I have.

Any ideas, opinions, help in general would be greatly appreciated ;).

Comment: Why not bind the event to both elements directly?

Comment: @Johan like $('.menu, .menu_wrapper')? I didn't think of that, but thanks, I'll try it ASAP.

Comment: Ok, please let me know how it went

Comment: @Johan It didn't work straight out, but I managed to derive a solution from it so thanks :). http://stackoverflow.com/a/13379275/887142

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I managed to solve the issue by using both a mouseover/mouseout event.**

This definitely isn't the most efficient way to handle this, but it's a decent fix:

```
   $('div.menu').mouseover(function() {
       $(this).find('div.menu_wrapper').show();
   });

   $('div.menu_wrapper').mouseout(function() {
       $(this).hide();'
   });
```

Comment: That will only hide `menu_wrapper` if you go over it with the mouse.  If you don't and you just leave `menu` then `menu_wrapper` will still stay open.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? (jQuery)

```
$(".menu").hover(
  function () {
    $(".menu_wrapper").show();
  },
  function () {
    $(".menu_wrapper").hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: Yes, but because `.menu_wrapper` has absolute positioning, it's not considered to be "wrapped" in it's parent element, therefore the hover event isn't triggered/continued when the cursor is moved to it.

Comment: @Avicinnian: can you add the .menu class to .menu_wrapper? <div class="menu_wrapper menu">

Comment: No because `.menu` has a bunch of styling properties. But I do like your thinking, I've already managed to solve it - but using a "middle-man" style like `.hover_event` or in your case `.menu` could work.